# Horew to write a parsePolynomial in Java?

Tags: java, string, polynomial-math

**parsePolynomial** -- this method takes one parameter **(a String)** and returns a **new Polynomial**.  The parameter is a String that represents a polynomial of the form similar to 2x^2+5.You must return a new instance of a Polynomial that correctly represents the string.

You will have to use some of the methods in the Java String class, so you should probably review the online documentation for the Java String class. For example, you might want to look at the *replaceAll(), lastIndexOf(), charAt() and substring()* methods (among others).

Comment: yes...due tomorrow at 8.

Comment: `You will have to use some of the methods in the Java String class, so you should probably review the online documentation for the Java String class.` Did you actually do that? Or you just want us to do it for you? :(

Comment: ya..i did..still confused..so.

Comment: Show the code you have problems with...

Comment: @Eric, most likely verbatim from the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First split at the `+`es so you get parts of either the form `2x^2` or `5`.

Next test if they contain `x^` and if yes use that to split them again so you get the coefficient and the exponent. Then parse them as double and int and you're done.

Comment: Nice way to walk the line, helpful without just outright giving the answer. <Thumbs up>